# How can I implement a MongoDB schema along with business logic in Rust?

Tags: mongodb, rust

I'm new to Rust and a frequent user of MongoDB. I usually use `node.js` + `Mongoose ODM`.

Is there any MongoDB ODM in RUST that implements a custom schema and business logic hooks like Mongoose ODM ? Or do I need to implement it myself inside the Rust's type system?

This is an example from Mongoose

```js
    const schema = kittySchema = new Schema(..);

    // they implement the 'meow' method in the Kitty Schema
    schema.method('meow', function () {
        console.log('meeeeeoooooooooooow');
    })
    
    // so anytime a Kitty schema instance is created
    const Kitty = mongoose.model('Kitty', schema);

    const fizz = new Kitty;
    
    // fizz as the instance of Kitty Schema automatically has meow() method
    fizz.meow(); // outputs: meeeeeooooooooooooow
```

As far as I know.. [mongodm-rs](https://github.com/Devolutions/mongodm-rs) doesn't do that
nor [Wither](https://github.com/thedodd/wither) nor [Avocado](https://docs.rs/avocado/0.6.0/avocado/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may not need an ODM. With [serde](https://serde.rs/) (which is used by all those ODMs), the "schema" is implemented on the struct itself, so you can add any methods you want with an `impl` block. It would look something like this:

```rust
    use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

    // Deriving from serde's Serialize and Deserialize, meaning this struct can be converted to and from BSON for storage and retrieval in MongoDB:
    #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
    struct Kitty {
        name: String,
    }

    impl Kitty {
        fn meow(&self) {
            println!("{} says 'meeeeeoooooooooooow'", &self.name);
        }
    }

    let fizz = Kitty {
        name: String::from("Fizz"),
    };

    fizz.meow();
```

This struct can be stored in MongoDB (because it derives Serialize and Deserialize) - to see how, check out my blog post [Up and Running with Rust and MongoDB](https://developer.mongodb.com/quickstart/rust-crud-tutorial/). There's some more up-to-date details about how to use serde with MongoDB in my colleague [Isabelle's post](https://developer.mongodb.com/article/serde-improvements/).

Comment: exactly what I need! Thank you for clear and precise answer